# Update, JPA. Как обновить сущность Entity?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, update

Использую Hibernate

Подгружаю объект User вот так:

```
public class Queries {
    public static <T> T firstOrNull(Query query) {
        List<T> result = query.list();
        return result.size() > 0? result.get(0) : null;
    }
}

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User byEmail(String email) {
        Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
        User u = Queries.firstOrNull(
                session.createQuery("from User u where u.email = '" + email + "'"));
        return u;
    }
}
```

И тут я как бы понимаю, что на самом деле вернется не User, а прокси, только вот могу ли я его обновить таким путем:

```
  - Загрузить User используя DAO
  - User.setName(...)
  - DAO.update(User)
```

Потому что при попытке выполнить этот код (который скрыто делает, то что я перечислил выше):

```
User u = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (name != null) u.setName(name);
accountService.update(u);
```

Я получаю исключение:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выполнении этого кода

```
User u = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
if (name != null) u.setName(name);
accountService.update(u);
```

Вы вытаскиваете юзера не из БД, а из Spring Security. Он там в памяти висит и оего нельзя изменять.
Если же вы хотите помянять имя юзера и не вытаскивать его из БД, а апдейтом, то лучше всего будет сделать getReference(Id) и сетером установить имя. Тогда в базу полетит только одна строка с апдейтом. И обязательно это делать в рамках одной транзаакции.